# Why does sudoers only allow me to set NOPASSWD for ALL?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, sudo

My situation is this: I'm trying to give the www-data user the ability to sudo-execute some shell scripts, so that I can have a page on my web server display system information (in PHP using shell_exec() ). To this end, I edited my sudoers file with the following line

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/evermind/scripts/*
```

to give Apache the ability to run scripts in that directory without needing a password for suoo. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, nor does (as a sanity check) specifying a *specific* script within that directory. shell_exec fails to execute the command, and gives the following error:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

This is where things get...strange. If I replace the path specification with "ALL" then everything works perfectly. Why is this? Is there a reason I can't specify NOPASSWD for individual files or directories?

For security reasons, I am extremely hesitant to allow www-data free reign over everything, even though the web application is extremely secure and there isn't an obvious way anyone could execute arbitrary commands.

Comment: `even though the web application is extremely secure and there isn't an obvious way anyone could execute arbitrary commands.`

Famous last words :D

Comment: Yep, which is exactly why going with "NOPASSWD: ALL" wasn't something I considered a viable option in spite of any apparent security.

Answer (score 2):

How about adding just using the directory path without the wildcard?

```
www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/evermind/scripts/
```

According to the [sudoers](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sudoers.5.html) man page:

```
A Cmnd_List is a list of one or more
commandnames, directories, and 
other aliases. ... A directory is a fully 
qualified path name ending in a '/'. 
When you specify a directory in a 
Cmnd_List, the user will be able to 
run any file within that directory (but 
not in any subdirectories therein).
```

Comment: That doesn't work either, unfortunately. My goal was to be able to have nested directories there, eventually, which is why I went the wildcard route. But when that didn't work, I tried taking it out.

Comment: @user297607 if that's your intention, then you're out of luck. The `*` explicitly does not match `/`, by intention. This is to prevent people doing stuff like `/home/evermind/scripts/../../../../bin/rm -rf /`. If you want it have access to nested directories, you'll have to list each subdirectory.

Comment: @jrp3 ah. I just noticed you said that even s specific script couldn't run. This is interesting. I'll test this out and get back.

Comment: Just came across this question doing cleanup... any further insight?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after stepping away from the problem for a day and coming back to it, I seem to have more or less solved my own problem.

Previously, the terminal command I was executing via shell_exec() was

```
sudo sh <path to my script>
```

Today, more or less for the sake of just trying *something*, I chmod'd my script to make it executable directly. Then, I changed the shell_exec() string to be

```
sudo <path to my script>
```

And voilà, it started working. Logic would seem to suggest that the culprit was actually the sh utility declaration, since that was the key distinction in the commands. If anyone knows what the deal with this was, though, I'd be really interested to know.

Comment: The deal here is simply that the command being executed as sudo is not the script in question, but `sh`, with the script an argument for `sh`. `sudo` uses `execve` to run the command according to the man page, and according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/3027353, `execve` processes the shebang line to run script. Since the check for permission presumably occurs *before* `execve` gets to its job, using `sh` will block it.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally if you are customizing what commands can be run via `sudo` you should be making these changes in a separate file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of editing the `sudoers` file directly. You should also always use `visudo` to edit the file(s). You should NEVER grant `NOPASSWD` on `ALL` commands.

Example:
`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myWebScript`

Insert your line granting permission:
`www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /home/evermind/scripts/`

The way you were calling it if you wanted to restrict is specifically to a directory for `sh` you would use:
`www-data ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/sh /home/evermind/scripts/`

I'm not sure why these scripts would require `sudo` access, typically you could just `chmod o+x scriptname.sh` and make sure that they were in a directory owned by the `www-data` user.

Then save and exit and `visudo` will warn you if you have any syntax errors.

You can run `sudo -l` to see the permissions that your user has been granted, if any of the user specific `NOPASSWD` commands appear BEFORE any `%groupyouarein ALL=(ALL) ALL` command in the output you will be prompted for your password.

If you find yourself creating lots of these sudoers.d files then perhaps you will want to create them named per user so they are easier to visualize. Keep in mind that the ordering of the FILE NAMES and of the RULES within the file is very important, the LAST one loaded wins, whether it is MORE or LESS permissive than the previous entries.

> You can control the file name ordering by using a prefix of 00-99 or aa/bb/cc, though also keep in mind that if you have ANY files that don't have numeric prefix, they will load after the numbered files, overriding the settings. This is because depending on your language settings the "lexical sorting" the shell uses sorts numbers first and then may interleave upper and lowercase when sorting in "ascending" order.

Try running `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | sort` and `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | LANG=C sort` to see whether your current language prints `AaBbCc` etc or `ABC` then `abc` to determine what the best "last" letter prefix to use would be.